# Could MySQL upgrade cause an INSERT statement to break?

Tags: mysql

I upgraded my Mac and hence upgraded my version of MySQL. Now this INSERT example from a trusted PHP book produces an error. It didn’t before.  Why?

I went from MySQL version 5.6.36 to 5.7.19. Could the change in MySQL versions cause the INSERT to break?

This is an example from the book “PHP and MySQL Web Development”

This is the database:

```
DESCRIBE customers;
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| customerid | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name       | char(50)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| address    | char(100)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| city       | char(30)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

This is the insert issued from a Bash Terminal:

```
INSERT INTO customers (name, city) values ('Melissa Jones', 'Nar Nar Goon North');
```

This error:

> ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'address' doesn't have a default value

I get this error when running the query via PHP

> Warning: mysqli_query(): Empty query in /Users/laptop/Sites/...

What am I missing or doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: The `address` field doesn't allow null values, but you have it declared with `DEFAULT NULL`.

Comment: There were lots of changes to the default values of settings in MySQL 5.7. The [release notes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/) list them.

Comment: MySQL 5.7 definitely tightens things up a lot. I've seen applications in CI and EE immediately break due to poor SQL that 5.5 accepts but 5.7 rejects. Looks like Oracle have finally whipped it into shape

Comment: Thanks again. Learned something new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOT NULL** - Each row must contain a value for that column, null values are not allowed

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_create_table.asp

As @Barmar pointed at comment, the `address` field have `NOT NULL` attributes and it should contain value when inserting a row.

```
INSERT INTO customers (name, address, city) values ('Melissa Jones', 'the_address', 'Nar Nar Goon North');
```

There is possibility you make an extra `NOT` when writing the script, it should be :

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
customerid INT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
address CHAR(100) NULL,
city CHAR(30) NOT NULL
)
```

Note : Making `name`, `city` and `address` as `CHAR` type field is not good. Read it why here : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/char.html

Comment: I saw that about the address. But since I was working with an example from a book, I figured it couldn't be wrong, especially since it worked before the upgrade. I reviewed the MySQL notes. One change with the sql_mode seems to have been the issue. I changed the mode to match that of the previous version and the error went away when issued from Bash but not the PHP.

Comment: @Hispanic100 Are you sure it have same table with `NOT NULL` attribute?

Comment: Yes. I just double checked. Created both with the book code. Thanks

Comment: Please avoid linking to w3schools when the [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/creating-tables.html) is far higher quality, kept up-to-date, and includes valuable community commentary to clarify otherwise confusing issues.

Comment: @tadman : Do you mean we can't link to another website when it have higher quality content? We just link a lower content website?

Comment: @ColourDalnet I mean w3schools is notoriously bad and the official documentation is generally quite good. The amount of damage w3schools has caused and continues to cause is immeasurable.

Comment: @tadman : Thank you, I have read it before but can't find good explanation about `NOT NULL`. But, thank you for correcting.

Comment: The MySQL documentation isn't organized as a tutorial, but it is [really thorough](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html).